# Describe JUnit test in report

Tags: junit, automated-tests, report

The JUnit report shows the names of the test methods in its report. Is there a way to provide some kind of description for the method (without using a huge descriptive name), so that the description shows up on the report?

I am using JUnit 4.11 (4.12 is still beta!)

Comment: duplicate of [JUnit Reports -- Test Method Descriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775096/junit-reports-test-method-descriptions)

Comment: The other question never came up during my extensive search! Guess I was not using a good search string. I had tried things like "JUnit description" "JUnit description name testng"... anyway, will vote to close it.